# Mini cart item price change magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, mini-cart

I am facing rounding issue in mini cart item price. I want to round price for mini cart item.But I am not sure from where it is coming? Please let me know where can I modify cart item price value. 
Any help will be appreciated

[image]
I just need to change format. I don't want to change price. In my case price is coming like 100.01$ but instead of that I want to show as 100$ only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is already same price 42.00. What you want to do ?

Comment: I have updated question. please check it.

Comment: What is the actual price of the product ?

Comment: Let say actual price of product is 100$ but if I will switch currency to AED then it will become 367.28 AED. So in this case instead of 367.28 AED I want t display like 368 AED in mini cart only. 
So if  I will get the file from where it is coming there I can round price.

Comment: Okay. You can use checkout_cart_product_add_after observer. And in observer execute method, you can write logic to round product price using ceil or floor so that it will be as per your requirement.

Comment: Yes but I just want to know from where  I can change format of this price. 
I checked it it is coming with Knockout.js. but I am not getting exact file where it is coming.

Comment: Please use my below answer which i have posted and comment me as soon as possible so that i can help u regarding this thanks

Comment: Hi @please let me know whether u got solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below Observer **currency_display_options_forming** from your custom module Here **Ewall_Account** is my custom module.

> Step 1: create **events.xml** file and keep the code in the below path
>   as shown
>
> > app/code/Ewall/Account/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
    <observer name="Ewall_Account_localize_currencysymbol_currency_display_options" instance="Ewall\Account\Observer\ModifyCurrencyOptions" />
    </event>
    </config>
```

> Step 2: app/code/Ewall/Account/Observer/ModifyCurrencyOptions.php

```
<?php

namespace Ewall\Account\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ModifyCurrencyOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CurrencySymbol\Model\System\CurrencysymbolFactory
     */
    protected $symbolFactory;

    const RIGHT = 16;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\CurrencySymbol\Model\System\CurrencysymbolFactory $symbolFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\CurrencySymbol\Model\System\CurrencysymbolFactory $symbolFactory)
    {
        $this->symbolFactory = $symbolFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Generate options for currency displaying with custom currency symbol
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/stackexchange.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $baseCode = $observer->getEvent()->getBaseCode();
        $logger->info("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx===>".$baseCode);
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
        $originalOptions = $currencyOptions->getData();
        $currencyOptions->setData($this->getCurrencyOptions($baseCode, $originalOptions));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get currency display options
     *
     * @param string $baseCode
     * @param array $originalOptions
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCurrencyOptions($baseCode, $originalOptions)
    {
        $currencyOptions = [];

        if ($baseCode == 'USD') {

            $currencyOptions['position'] = self::RIGHT; // switch currency symbol position to the RIGHT
        }

        return array_merge($originalOptions, $currencyOptions);
    }
}
```

> Step 3: Please use the below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

> Step 4: Please find the output below

[image: please see the output]

Comment: Thansk for your answer let me try this.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply and get back with u r comments

Comment: Actually I want to format price for mini cart item only

Answer (score 0):

1.Create **di.xml** in Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="Vendor\Module\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
</config>
```

2.Create file **DefaultItem.php** inside Vendor\Module\CustomerData and do what you want in price values here they will reflect on mini cart.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Default item
 */
class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
         /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
         */
        protected $imageHelper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $msrpHelper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
         */
        protected $urlBuilder;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool
         */
        protected $configurationPool;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $checkoutHelper;

        /**
         * Escaper
         *
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
         */
        private $escaper;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper = null
    ) {
        $this->configurationPool = $configurationPool;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->msrpHelper = $msrpHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
        $this->escaper = $escaper ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class);
    }

    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        $productName = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->item->getProduct()->getName());

        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_id' => $this->item->getProduct()->getId(),
            'product_name' => $productName,
            'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
            'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
            'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
            'weight' => $this->item->getProduct()->getWeight(),
            'product_image' => [
                'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
            ],
            'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
        ];
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Possibly this worked in a previous version of M2 but not as of 2.4 at least, probably earlier.  This function is not called when creating the minicart.