# How to move currency icon in magento 2

Tags: magento2, currency-symbol

My site there is display price like **20,00 CA$** but i want like this **CA$ 20,00**

i find the code on

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

can any buddy suggest which code i change it for

```
<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer())  ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />

    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

Comment: hi @Brijesh Patel please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183694/mini-cart-item-price-change-magento-2/183801#183801

Comment: Please confirm whether u are looking for the solution on product view page?

Comment: i want to change there code not any other extra module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code :

**app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="vendor_extension_change_currency_position" instance="Vendor\Extension\Model\Observer\Changecurrencyposition" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Observer\Changecurrencyposition.php**

```
<?php        
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Observer;    

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;    
    class Changecurrencyposition implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {    
            $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();    
            $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);  
            return $this;
        }    
    }
```

than apply below command :

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**hope its work for you..**