# How to move currency symbol using currency_display_options_forming event hook in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, currency, magento2.4.5, currency-symbol

I am upgrading from 2.4.3 to 2.4.5 and see that the code to move currency symbol from left to right of price is not working. How can I update the code to get it to work? Currently I'm using the currency_display_options_forming event hook to add currency options like this (similar to this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/286889/109359):

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
    $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);
    $currencyOptions->setData('symbol', ',-');

    return $this;
}
```

The symbol part is working like in 2.4.3, but position is not.

Comment: I ended up using an extension instead: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-currency-formatter. It is not using the currency_display_options_forming event hook, so I basically avoided the issue.

Comment: Can you please tell us that your magento 2.4.5 is running fine or not. I want to use Magento 2.4.5 for my site?

Answer (score 0):

Did you cleared cache / static content?

You can try these commands:

```
rm -rf genenerated/
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Also, did you use the 'Magento_Currency' module as a sequence in module.xml?

Comment: Yes, cleared cache/static and also tried adding Magento_Currency in sequence in module.xml, but no change. I can change symbol and I see the change after clearing cache, so it seems to me that the position attribute is simply not working like before.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled around on this issue today with a Magento 2.4.5 shop. Since no other solutions worked, I started digging through a lot of private methods etc. I found a solution rewriting `\Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter` to change the pattern given to [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php).

This way, the currency will be displayed after the numbers.

To make life a bit easier, I've created a module for it,

[codepeak/magento2-module-movecurrency](https://github.com/codepeak/magento2-module-movecurrency)

Hope this can help anyone else.