Change Currency Symbol Position Magento 2.4.6
Hi Dears I want to Change Currency Symbol Position from Right to Left on AdminPanel For Example:
2400 SAR to :
ریال السعوديs 2400
2400 UAE to :
درهم الاماراتs 2400
I tried this soulution but doesn't works.

Try this given module : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360754/how-to-move-currency-symbol-using-currency-display-options-forming-event-hook-in
